# AdMob video-ad in GADBannerView is keep using CPU after a tab-change in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, admob, gadbannerview, google-mobile-ads

**My setup:**

There's a `UITabBarController`. In the first tab - there's a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController` as a root viewcontroller.

In the table of `UITableViewController`, one of the cells contains a `GADBannerView`

In the cell with the bannerView, I'm loading the ad like this:

```
    var bannerView: GADBannerView = GADBannerView()
    ......
    bannerView?.adUnitID = "<my adUnitId>"
    bannerView?.adSize = kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.contentURL = "<my site>"
    bannerView?.load(request)
```

**Problem:**

I've noticed, that if the ad contains the video/animation - after switching between tabs - the **CPU usage is still high and remains on 15-20%** load forever (until you kill the app).

Actual ad looks like this:

[image]

A couple observations:

- if instead of the video-ad - there's a static-image-ad - there's no issue. To me this issue looks like there's some "pause animation" which is not being called for the video-ads.
- happens on both iOS11 and iOS12
- `func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView)` is **not** being called, i.e. the framework knows that the ad is no longer on the screen

This is how processes look like (after switching to another, ad-free tab):
[image]

**Version of the AdMob:**

'Firebase/AdMob', '~>**5.15.0**' (from cocoapods)

Any suggestions are very welcomed.

Comment: UITabBarController keeps the root UIViewControllers associated with its tabs alive in RAM after they have been instantiated even when you switch away to a different tab. If the ads in you UITableView are actually too RAM hungry to be kept alive, you're likely going to need to clean them up yourself when users switch away from the tab.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @Dare . I did `removeFromSuperview` on the banner and nil the reference afterwards on `viewWillDisappear` - it's keep the CPU high (any better ways to _clean up_?) . Plus, what bugs me - the refresh stops working - so the framework is kind of know that ad shouldn't be on the screen..

Comment: Are you calling destroy() on both banner and interstitial ads?

Comment: @Dare I very well can be just stupid - but I don't see anything similar to destroy() (or synonyms) for `GADBannerView` class? (I've also set to `nil` both `rootViewController` and `delegate` for the banner - still same 16% CPU load)

Comment: Hi Konstantin, I encountered similar problem of high CPU load when loading native video ads, even when the cell is off screen, with latest GMA SDK. Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: @AllenHsu hey Allen. I wouldn't say that I've exactly _fixed_ it - rather just updated cocoapods couple of times and waited for the issue to go away. From my observations over the last 2-3 years with AdMob - this is the most legit strategy.

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov :  Is it possible display different Ads on each recurring items?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved it by removing the banner every time the ad goes off screen add (re-) add it if it's visible again. This might happen in three cases:

1. Cell is scrolled out of the visible area.
   Implemented in:

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

2. Navigate to subview.
   Implemented in:

`viewWillDisappear`

3. App goes to background
   Add observer for `appDidEnterBackground`